# On a projection from the regular representation of $\mathfrak{S}_n$ to the Specht module

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{S}_n]$ be the regular representation of the symmetric group and $S^{\lambda}$ the Specht module associated to the partition $\lambda \vdash n$. We know that we have the decomposition 
$$
\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{S}_n] \cong \displaystyle \bigoplus_{\lambda \vdash n} f_{\lambda}S^{\lambda},
$$
where $f_{\lambda}$ is the number of standard tableaux of shape $\lambda$. In perticular, there exists morphisms of representations $S^{\lambda} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{S}_n]$ and $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{S}_n] \twoheadrightarrow S^{\lambda}$.

Can we construct those morphisms in a way that the composition is the identity (on $S^{\lambda}$) and that the projection is defined straightforwardly (i.e. described for each element of $\mathfrak{S}_n$ and extended linearly, instead of decomposing $\mathbb{C}[\mathfrak{S}_n]$) ?

Comment: Denote the group algebra by $A$. A common way of constructing Specht modules is via Young Symmetrisers, where one defines a certain element $y_\lambda \in A$, then we have $S^\lambda = A y_\lambda$. This gives both the inclusion (as the subspace of $A$ of elements of the form $a y_\lambda$) and the projection, sending $a$ to $a y_\lambda$. The composition of these is not quite the identity, but the scalar $x$ where $y_\lambda^2 = x y_\lambda$, so you could normalise to make it work.